# padding number when writing to file in .net

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-ise

The following .NET script in Powershell ISE

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "t.txt"
$number = 1
1..500000 | % {
      $stream.Write("TEST_825A_")
      $stream.WriteLine($number)
$number +=1
}

$stream.close()
```

Outputs a text file with

```
TEST_825A_1

TEST_825A_2

TEST_825A_3

...

TEST_825A_500000
```

I need it to be padded with zeroes to 8 digits

```
TEST_825A_00000001

...

TEST_825A_00500000
```

This is not a language I am even close to native in, and Googling doesn't seem to help.(Or I don't understand how to implement the answers)

Could someone please help me out here?

EDIT:

Working code

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "t.txt"
$number = 1
1..1000 | % {
      $stream.Write("TEST_825A_")
      $stream.WriteLine($number.ToString("00000000"))
$number += 1

}

$stream.close()
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why are you using .NET stuff in PowerShell? There are existing cmdlets, such as `"YourString" | Out-File "t.txt" -Append`?

Comment: Because .NET stuff is supposedly the fastest to execute when generating very large output, Example with 10K lines:

 Method

 

Time to completion

‘>>’

 

29 s

Outfile and [Array]

 

27 s

export-csv

 

22 s

StreamWriter

 

1.5 s

Source:http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you writing to very large files in this case, or is it a premature optimization?

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to generate millions of lines, so it needs to be efficient.
The solution above is fast enough. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could us ToString with a formatting mask:

```
$number = 1
$number.ToString("00000000")
```

gives `00000001`

Comment: Thanks!
That was simple :-)

It had to be put inside the Writeline, I have updated the original text with working code.

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect this to change the runtime extensively but you could also use a string [`PadLeft()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The particular reason this might be slower is because you need to do a cast first.

```
$number = 5
([string]$number).PadLeft(8,"0")
```

Still, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Results = (1..500000) | % { "TEST_825A_$($_.ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"))" }
$Results -Join "`r`n" | Set-Content "t.txt"
```

This will do 1 write to the HHD.. instead of multiple ones.

I sampled it on 1000..:

```
Measure-Command {
  $Results = (1..1000) | % { "TEST_825A_$($_.ToString().PadLeft(8, "0"))" }
  $Results -Join "`r`n" | Set-Content "t1.txt"
}
```

**TotalMilliseconds : 45.6615**

```
Measure-Command {
  $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "Y:\Desktop\t2.txt"
  $number = 1
  1..1000 | % {
    $stream.Write("TEST_825A_")
    $stream.WriteLine($number.ToString("00000000"))
    $number += 1
  }
  $stream.close()
}
```

**TotalMilliseconds : 63.435**